# Burninate [heuristic]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [heuristic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heuristic) tag has only one question, no description, no synonyms and no wiki entry.  The [only question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251214/scheduling-covid-19-testing-in-a-hospital-using-a-heuristic) using it has four other tags and a comment pointing out that the use of the word "heuristic" (which appears in the title) is ill-chosen in the context of  this question. Seems like a good candidate for elimination.

Answer (score 7):

One-off tags are automatically deleted after six months, according to the answer I got [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341923/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. So unless somebody else uses the tag meanwhile, there's no need to take action.

Comment: That link was helpful.  If I understand the discussion there correctly, it would only potentially require intervention if there were 2 or more questions using it.  Is that also your understanding?

Comment: @Edward yes, exactly.

Comment: @Edward Feel free to edit it out and replace it by a better tag. The tag should cease to exist a lot sooner that way.